# Programmatically submitting a Gravity Form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravityforms

I have created a gravity form and would like to programmatically submit it. I want to create a template in WordPress that is a custom HTML form, all the data then get's submitted to the actual form for the Gravity Forms logic to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the GFAPI::submit_form() method:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#submit-form

You can take the data submitted in the HTML form, format the data into a structure that Gravity Forms expects and then pass it to this function to trigger an artificial submission.